# jQuery accordion - quick show/hide

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a page with an accordion that contains search criteria. Once a person clicks the search button, the criteria closes (I simulate a click on the accordion heading).  This works great.

The problem is when there the user provides invalid input, my AJAX call returns and I attempt to show the search criteria again before the accordion finished closing (again with a simulated click on the accordion heading).  This of course fails to open the search criteria.

A simple example of this would be double clicking on the accordion heading.  Nothing happens if the accordion is in transition during this double click.

How to avoid this in my situation?  NOTE: It seems to be more of a problem in Chrome/FF than in IE as IE does not animate the accordion open/collapse.

Basic idea from the code where #section1 represents the accordion heading:

```
$("#section1").click();
//some very fast AJAX.
$("#section1").click();
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeyfreake/gGaJn/2/

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `stop` on the children of the accordion:

```
$("#accordion").children().stop(true, true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gGaJn/9/

Comment: Thank you @Brandon, much appreciated. This solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use `async: false` parameter in your Ajax call. This will let the Ajax call finish executing before the second click.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Or you can perform the second click in the `success` function:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function (data) {
        $("#section1").click();
    },
   ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob. This is a valid solution, but I have to choose the answer provided by Brandon due to it maintaining the asynchronous functionality I prefer.